# tuProlog - using multiple files with consult - can't get engine to load additional files with consult(otherFile.pl)

Tags: java, prolog, tuprolog

Edit: Clarity - the main .pl file loads, it's all the subfiles that it has been told to load which don't load. (all the consult('subfile.pl').)

I have a Java project that uses tuProlog. It calls a theory as:

```
Theory theory = new Theory(":-consult('main.pl').");
        engine.setTheory(theory);
```

This is as per the manual.
file.pl exists in the same folder as other prolog files.
Inside of main.pl, I have further

```
consult('otherfile.pl').
```

statements to load additional files (several).

The folder structure is:

```
src/main.pl
src/Prolog_Files/otherfile.pl (multiple)
src/main/java/JavaStuff
```

I can't get the engine to load the theories that I've told it to consult inside of the main file.pl

- I have tried: giving it absolute path instead of just filename.
- moving files around.

I'm wondering if there is something about usage of tuProlog I'm not understanding?

The theory works when loaded with:

```
Theory theory = new Theory(new FileInputStream(url_of_file)).
```

However, this is causing me issues when building the jar, as it can't find the file location.

Am I attempting to load the file correctly? Are my consults inside of the main .pl file correct?

Could someone please post an example of how this should be done if not? The manual doesn't elaborate very much on this topic.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The manual is slightly outdated in parts - it says to use consult/1, whereas elsewhere it states that consult/1 is deprecated, whereas include/1 is the replacement.

Secondly, when using 2p.jar, it reads Prolog files from the Project root as its root. When creating a jar, 2p.jar cannot be inside of the project jar. They should be in relative folders, and 2p.jar reads Prolog files with the location of 2p.jar as root. It doesn't seem that it can read inside of project jar.

Hopefully that's clear enough!